# MSUnit: Assert.AreEqual fails trees

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tdd

I have to test the equality of trees. In other other words objects which contains `List<T>` with childs and the childs also contains `List<T>` with childs and so on.

I've found that you can test List with CollectionAssert, however it does not work that well with composites.

Any suggestions? MSUnit is my test library.

**Example**

```
IReagentComposed bronzeBarParsed = (from n in composedCrafts where n.ItemId == 2841 select n).Single();

IReagentComposed bronzeBar = new Craft()
{
    ItemId = 2841,
    Profession = Profession.Mining,
    Quantity = 0,
    QuantityCrafted = 0,
    Skill = 50,
    Reagents = new List()
    {
        new Craft()
        {
            ItemId = 2840,
            Quantity = 0,
            Skill = 1,
            Profession = Profession.Mining,
            Reagents = new List()
            {
                new Reagent()
                {
                    ItemId = 2770,
                    Quantity = 1
                }
            }
        },
        new Craft()
        {
            ItemId = 3576,
            Quantity = 0,
            Skill = 50,
            Profession = Profession.Mining,
            Reagents = new List()
            {
                new Reagent()
                {
                    ItemId = 2771,
                    Quantity = 1
                }
            }
        }
    }
};

Assert.AreEqual(bronzeBar, bronzeBarParsed);
```

**Craft and Reagent**

```
public class Craft : IReagentComposed
{
    public int QuantityCrafted { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set;}
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public int Skill { get; set; }
    public Profession Profession { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable Reagents { get; set; }


    public override bool Equals(object other)
    {
        if (other == null || GetType() != other.GetType()) return false;

        IReagentComposed o = other as IReagentComposed;

        return o != null && this.Quantity == o.Quantity &&
                this.ItemId == o.ItemId &&
                this.Profession == o.Profession &&
                this.Reagents == o.Reagents && //also tried Equals
                this.Skill == o.Skill;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

public class Reagent : IReagent
{
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object other)
    {
        if (other == null || GetType() != other.GetType()) return false;

        IReagent o = other as IReagent;

        return o != null && o.ItemId == this.ItemId && o.Quantity == this.Quantity;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you overloaded the .Equals operator? If not, it will just be checking object identity. If you have, please show us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        return o != null && this.Quantity == o.Quantity &&
                this.ItemId == o.ItemId &&
                this.Profession == o.Profession &&
                this.Reagents == o.Reagents && //also tried Equals
                this.Skill == o.Skill;
```

The Reagents are unlikely to match, they are distinct List objects.  List<> doesn't override Equals although it isn't that clear what actual type you use.  Write a little helper function that takes two lists of reagents and checks for equality.  You'd typically start at comparing List<>.Count and then work down the elements one by one.

Answer (score 0):

Added a extension method for `IEnumberable<T>`:

```
public static class IEnumberableExtensions
{
    public static bool AreEnumerablesEqual<T>(this IEnumerable<T> x, IEnumerable<T> y)
    {
        if (x.Count() != y.Count()) return false;

        bool equals = false;

        foreach (var a in x)
        {
            foreach (var b in y)
            {
                if (a.Equals(b))
                {
                    equals = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (!equals)
            {
                return false;
            }

            equals = false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```